how to prevent terminal stop when error occur during the kafka connection?
1) kafka code
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { KafKaQueueNames } from "../dto/enum/kakaQueueNames";
import { Kafka, Producer } from 'kafkajs';

@Injectable()
export class KafkaProducerService {
    private readonly kafka = new Kafka({
        clientId: process.env["kafka_client_id"],
        brokers: [ process.env["kafka_broker"] ]
    })
    private readonly producer: Producer = this.kafka.producer({
        allowAutoTopicCreation: true,
        transactionTimeout: 30000
    })
    async onApplicationShutdown() {
        await this.producer.disconnect();
    }
    async onModuleInit() {
        await this.producer.connect();
    }
    async sendToKafka(payload: any, pTopic: string) {
        await this.producer.send({
            topic: pTopic,
            messages: [{
                key: uuidv4(), value: payload
            }],
        });
    }

    async sendToExceptionQueue(payload: any) {
        await this.producer.send({
            topic: KafKaQueueNames.EDDA_EXCEPTIONS_QUEUE,
            messages: [{
                key: uuidv4(), value: payload
            }],
        });
    }

}


the above is my kafka connection whenver the app start kafka connection is connected and in any mixed time it gets connection timeout and stop the terminal in production .so how can i stop the connection timeout error and prevent the terminal from any bugs happend.
